# Set the same value for all existing keys in an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutabledictionary, kvc

In KVC, I usually use `setValues:forKeyPath:` to set the same value for objects in a collection. E.g.:

```
NSMutableArray <SomeClass *> *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SomeClass *obj = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    obj.stringProp = @(i).stringValue;
    [arr addObject:obj];
}

NSLog(@"- %@", [arr valueForKeyPath:@"stringProp"]);
[arr setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:@{@"stringProp" : @"Same same!"}];

NSLog(@"- %@", [arr valueForKeyPath:@"stringProp"]);
[arr setValue:@"Another" forKeyPath:@"stringProp"];

NSLog(@"- %@", [arr valueForKeyPath:@"stringProp"])
```

But, for a dictionary, can we use that as well? Now I've gotta set values manually:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict;
//... setupValues
NSString *valueToSet = @"Hehe";
for (NSString *key in myDict) {
    [myDict setObject:valueToSet forKey:key];
}
```

Is there a simple solution for a dictionary, like the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a function for that (I guess it don't), but in case you gonna need to do that multiple times, you can add a function to NSMutableDictionary to help you with that:

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary (NSMutableDictionarySetAllKeysObject)
-(void)setAllKeysObject:(nonnull id)object;
@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (NSMutableDictionarySetAllKeysObject)
-(void)setAllKeysObject:(nonnull id)object
{
    for (NSString *key in self.allKeys) {
        [self setObject:object forKey:key];
    }
}
@end
```

So you would be able to do that:

```
NSString *valueToSet = @"Hehe";
[myDict setAllKeysObject:valueToSet];
```

Comment: probably they don't have a function for that (yet?). I'll accept your answer in a few days, in case someone found a way I asked for :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use `allValues` method to get all values as an `NSArray` first. Then get a mutable copy of the array. Lastly, use any of the KVC methods you mentioned in your question on the mutable array (`setValuesForKeysWithDictionary`, `setValue:forKeyPath:`, etc...)

---

Based on your example

```
[[[myDict allValues] mutableCopy] setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:@{@"stringProp" : @"Same same!"}];`

[[[myDict allValues] mutableCopy] setValue:@"Another" forKeyPath:@"stringProp"];`
```

Or implement a category

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary (KVCForValues)

- (void)setValuesForValuesWithKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)keyedValues;
- (void)setValue:(nullable id)value forValuesWithKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;

@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (KVCForValues)

- (void)setValuesForValuesWithKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)keyedValues {
  [[[self allValues] mutableCopy] setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:keyedValues];
}

- (void)setValue:(id)value forValuesWithKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
  [[[self allValues] mutableCopy] setValue:value forKeyPath:keyPath];
}

@end
```

And make use of it

```
[myDict setValuesForValuesWithKeysWithDictionary:@{@"stringProp" : @"Same same!"}];

[myDict setValue:@"Another" forValuesWithKeyPath:@"stringProp"];
```

---

This approach **makes sense** when you want to use KVC approach that is not possible with the accepted answer.

---

**Concrete example**

Assuming `SomeClass` is defined as follows

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someProperty;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger anotherProperty;

@end

@implementation SomeClass

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someProperty=%@, anotherProperty=%d", self.someProperty, (int)self.anotherProperty];
}

@end
```

Executing the following

```
SomeClass *value1 = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
value1.someProperty = @"aaa";
value1.anotherProperty = 111;

SomeClass *value2 = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
value2.someProperty = @"bbb";
value2.anotherProperty = 222;

SomeClass *value3 = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
value3.someProperty = @"ccc";
value3.anotherProperty = 333;

NSDictionary *someDictionary = @{@"key1": value1, @"key2": value2, @"key3": value3};

NSLog(@"%@", someDictionary);
```

Will produce the following output

```
key1 = "someProperty=aaa, anotherProperty=111";
key2 = "someProperty=bbb, anotherProperty=222";
key3 = "someProperty=ccc, anotherProperty=333";
```

After executing

```
[[[someDictionary allValues] mutableCopy] setValue:@"SameValue" forKeyPath:@"someProperty"];

NSLog(@"%@", someDictionary);
```

The output would be

```
key1 = "someProperty=SameValue, anotherProperty=111";
key2 = "someProperty=SameValue, anotherProperty=222";
key3 = "someProperty=SameValue, anotherProperty=333";
```

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the question. In my sample (for `NSDictionary`), I ask if I can set a *VALUE* to *ALL KEYS* in a flat dictionary by using KVC. Like, a Dict with keys and values: `[0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"]`, I'd like to make it `[0: "Same", 1: "Same", 2: "Same", 3: "Same"]`. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Eddie That's exactly what the code above does. I've added a sample code. In any case, the NSDictionary's values in your comment should be of type `SomeClass` as in your question and not `NSString`. It won't work for `NSString` even with `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: That's a good explanation. However, it's impossible to set a value directly to the keys but need objects as a bridging and set values to the object's properties instead, am I correct? Like, it's not possible to set it as in my previous comment, is it?

Comment: @Eddie Not possible